# How to delete nodes containing multiple attributes from XML variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have some XML being passed into a SQL stored procedure that looks like this:

```
<root>
    <category>
        <property id="blah" otherID="blahblah" year="2015">
        <property id="blah" otherID="notBlahBlah" year="2015">
    </category>
</root>
```

I want to delete a property node from this using SQL based on multiple node attributes. For example, say I wanted to delete a property with id="blah" and otherID="blahblah". How could I do this? Thank you.

This is the code I have so far based on my best guess of how to do this having read some XQUERY documentation, but it's not working correctly:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML
SET @XML = '<root>
               <category>
                   <property id="blah" otherID="blahblah" year="2015">
                   <property id="blah" otherID="notBlahBlah" year="2015">
               </category>
            </root>'

UPDATE @XML.nodes('/root/category/property') 
SET data.modify('delete /root/category/property[id="blah", otherID="blahblah"]')
```

Comment: Please provide sample outcome and what you have tried so far.  [Here is a link for what is considered necessary for a good SQL question](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: XML support is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML

SET @XML = '
<root>
               <category>
                   <property id="blah" otherID="blahblah" year="2015"/>
                   <property id="blah" otherID="notblahblah" year="2015"/>
               </category>
            </root>'

SET @XML.modify('delete /root/category/property[@id="blah" and @otherID="blahblah"]')

SELECT @XML
```